# Database Schema - MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a newbie with creating a robust database system. But after completing, my challenge lies with two table, `User table and Category table`. Each user in the database must create categories for their products. Initially, i made it a many to many relation (creating a pivot table `user_category table`) but now, i having doubts.

Can i still use the many to many relationship for the user and category table?

Comment: How can you make many to many for **A user who has many categories** ?

Comment: Can 2 users have the same category or are the categories individual per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2 or more users can have the same categories I would recommend to use this structure:

```
user table:
|user_id|user_name|...

categories table:
|category_id|category_name|...

user_categories table:
|user_id|category_id|
```

If a category is unique per user I would add the `user_id` column in the category table

```
user table:
|user_id|user_name|...

categories table:
|category_id|category_name|user_id|...
```